# Should I be using lambdas in TDD?

Tags: java, c#, unit-testing, lambda

In TDD, wouldn't lambda's be detrimental? How do we test the functionality of a lambda that is encapsulated within another function? It would seem to me that you wouldn't be able to test that lambda to ensure that it **was** working as expected. The point of unit tests is to test small units of code. Lambdas are small units of code that seem to me, untestable.

Any help, opinions, clarification, or links would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you feel lambdas are "untestable"? If you're talking about trying to write a test to check a predicate passed into say `IEnumerable<T>.Where(x => blah)`, you should instead be testing the actual method that is using that code with different test cases/parameters.

Comment: @TyCobb That's exactly my question. And from what everyone is saying, it seems that it is appropriate to test the encapsulating function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The point of unit tests is to test small units of code.

That doesn't mean that you should feel compelled to write a unit test for *all* small units of code. Private methods can be small units of code, but you don't test them directly. You test them by testing the code that calls them. Same goes for lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

I, personally, would be testing the code that calls the lambda, not the lambda itself. Should you wish to test the lambda itself, you can expose the lambda public-ally and test it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use lambdas even if you desire to test your code.

A lambda misbehaving will lead to the parent function misbehaving as long as the tests for it cover it well.

Finally, some lambdas are indeed better off extracted. Think before spawning lambdas around, and only use them where they make sense and improve the comprehension of the code. If the parent of a lambda misbehaves, it should be easy to pinpoint the issue inside the lambda, if it's there.